# Is there an easy way to join two ILists with joint key

Tags: c#, linq

I want to join two `IList<int[]>` by the unique identifier key listed there and concatenate them into a new one. It's exactly the same thing when we `JOIN` two tables in SQL server, but wonder if it is possible to do it easily in c#?

Code is similar to this:

```
int[] a1 = {1,10}; int[] a2 = {2,20}; int[] a3 = {3,30};
int[] b1 = {1,-1}; int[] b2 = {2,-2}; int[] b3 = {3,-3};

IList<int[]> List1 = new List<int[]>();
IList<int[]> List2 = new List<int[]>();

List1.Add(a1);List1.Add(a2);List1.Add(a3);
List2.Add(b1);List2.Add(b2);List2.Add(b3);

IList<int[]> ListFinal = new List<int[]>();
// I want to the ListFinal be <{1,10,-1},{2,20,-2},{3,30,-3}>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

var ListFinal = List1.Join(List2,
        (inner) => inner[0], // return key of each item in list1
        (outer) => outer[0], // return key of each item in list2 to be matched
        (inner,outer) => new[]{ inner[0],inner[1],outer[1] }
    ).ToList();
```

Also this function make inner-outer join as its parameter name stated. Some item might missing because it cannot find it's pair